# Probability of getting all pattern combinations in moving window over a vector of characters

Tags: pr.probability

So, I am in need of an indication of literature or where to start.
I am having a problem consisting of reading a vector of characters (for example, there are n=4 possible characters {A,B,C,D}) using a moving window in the format [1 0 1].
For example:
The vector is:

> ABBCDE

and results in a reading of

> (A,B)(B,C)(B,D)(C,E)

I am having trouble calculating what length of character vector is needed to contain all possible combinations of characters. Considering a random vector.

PS: a difficulty I have is in the overlapping of the patterns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expected length needed to see all patterns of length $k$ in an alphabet of size $a$ is $k \ln(a) a^k (1+o(1))$.
See Propositions 11.9 and 11.10 in [1]  for the case $a=2$.

[1] Levin, David A., and Yuval Peres. Markov chains and mixing times. Vol. 107. American Mathematical Soc. second ed., with contributions by E. Wilmer, 2017.
https://pages.uoregon.edu/dlevin/MARKOV/markovmixing.pdf

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much Mr. @Yuval Peres!